# Showing Windows apps in Parallels Coherence with mac-style title bar with red/yellow/green dots on left?

Tags: windows, window-manager, parallels-desktop

On my Mac, I need to use some Windows-only apps in a Windows 10 Parallels 11 VM. One thing I find annoying is remembering to click in the upper-right to close Windows windows but clicking in the upper-left to close Mac windows.

Does anyone know of any Windows 10 solutions that will move the close/minimize/maximize buttons in Windows titlebars to the left side of the window like on Mac OS X?  There used to be an app called LeftSider but I don't think this is compatible with Windows 10.

I don't particularly care whether the buttons look like Mac buttons or not-- just want them in the same spot so I can rely on muscle memory and won't have to think where to click depending on the window.

I run in Coherence mode on Parallels 11 in the latest El Capitan Mac OS, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I always found changing between Mac and Windows extremely annoying for that reason as well, and was totally excited to find out that you can close any Windows window that has an X, by simply double-clicking the far upper-left-hand corner.

I cannot say about Win10 specifically, since I don't have that installed anywhere, but I know it worked from XP, all the way through Win8.

Comment: Unfortunately, some Windows apps (notably Office apps like Outlook) put things in the upper left corner so that trick isn't universal. Was hoping for a more universal solution.  Glad to see I wasn't the only person looking for this shortcut!